# Why can't I place the rook in front of the queen?

Tags: rules, queens, rooks

I was playing chess this afternoon on my mac, as human vs computer. In the position below:

```
[FEN "6k1/5pp1/2p3bp/pqP1P3/2R3P1/PPQ5/4K3/8 w - - 0 24"]
```

I tried to place the Rook in front of Black's Queen (b4), but this action was blocked and the Rook remained in the same place. Later I completed the game by making another move.

Why is this so? Why can't I place the Rook in front of Black's Queen? Please explain this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Rook on c4 is pinned against the your King by the black Queen. Thus you can't move it without exposing your King to the Queen's wrath.

Answer (score 11):

You wouldn't *want* to place the rook in front of the queen at b4. Because it can be captured by the pawn on a5.

Even if you do want to, you *can't* move the rook in front of the queen (or anywhere else), because it is pinned to your king by the queen.

It's fortunate that `Rb4` was an illegal move, because it would have been a big mistake.

You should, instead, move the king to e3, unpinning it, and bringing it closer to your pawns.